# Почему метод не дожидается return?

Tags: c#, асинхронность

Есть такой метод

```
 public async Task<string> Request(string login, string password)
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    { "domain", key.domain},
                    { "login", login },
                    { "password", password }
                };

        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("PddToken", key.token);
            var response = await client.PostAsync("https://pddimp.yandex.ru/api2/admin/email/add",content);

            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            dynamic obj = JObject.Parse(responseBody);
            string answer = (string)obj.domain.success.error;
            return answer;
        }

    }
```

Вызываю я его таким образом.

```
CreateMail mailCreator = new CreateMail();
var resultJson = mailCreator.Request(LoginTextBox.Value, PassTextBox.Value);
```

Начинаю шагать, параметры попадают в метод, доходит до строчки

```
var response = await client.PostAsync("https://pddimp.yandex.ru/api2/admin/email/add",content);
```

Все и здесь все обрывается и в `return` я не могу получить и посмотреть, какой ответ мне пришел. Почему это происходит?

Возможно ли сделать то же самое, только без многопоточности?

Answer (score 3):

Вместо использования "var" поставьте то, что хотите получить (string).

```
string resultJson = mailCreator.Request(LoginTextBox.Value, PassTextBox.Value);
```

Сейчас у вас в resultJson запихивается сам Task со статусом WaitingForActivation. Вам нужно запросить результат у этого Task-а. Т.е. поставить await.

```
string resultJson = await mailCreator.Request(LoginTextBox.Value, PassTextBox.Value);
```

Предложение await вернет ваш поток в другое место, где этот поток требуется. А когда ответ будет получен, то поток снова продолжит выполнение метода после await. Это собственно и есть имитация многопотчности.

UPD: Если вы не хотите чтобы а контекст возвращался, то используйте так:

```
Task<string> task = mailCreator.Request(LoginTextBox.Value, PassTextBox.Value);
string resultJson = task.Result;
```

Comment: а чем отличается `await task` от `task.Result` кроме того, что это блокирующий вызов? Всё равно этот код будет выполняться в контексте, который был до создания Task'а

Comment: Использования `task.Result` надо по возможности избегать. Он может неявным образом приводить к дедлокам в некоторых случаях.

Comment: Попробовал вашим способом, который самом внизу. Та же ситуация.

Comment: await task - не блокирует поток. На этом месте метод делится на "до await" и "после await". Поток входит в task как в обычный метод и когда видит в этом методе await, то возвращается в первый метод и выполняет оставшуюся часть метода. Если точнее то поток возвращается тогда, когда ему сказали вернуться. Если написать await Task.Yield() то это будет конкретным указанием в этом месте вернуть контекст.

Comment: а task.Result (для Task<T>) или task.Wait() (для обычного Task) заблокирует поток в данном месте. Т.е. поток будет простаивать до тех пор, пока не будет получен результат или метод не завершится

Comment: @shatoidil почитайте про yield return в C#, по этому методу работает await.

Comment: кстати, к сожалению async и await нормально дебажится только на windows 8. Там показывается в стеке вызовов что было до и после await.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что пока метод ждёт асинхронную операцию, выполнение кода продолжается в других местах. Просто поставь breakpoint после await и запусти.

Comment: Попробовал, обрыв идет на первом await, мне нужно значение return вывести в label

Comment: @shatoidil, предположение. Ты делаешь что-то не то и там на самом деле выкидывается Exception. 1. Попробуй сделать синхронный запрос и посмотри, что произойдёт. 2. Попробуй добавить try-catch с брейкпоинтом в catch.